# Upload images from my server to password protected site

Tags: php, mysql, data-transfer, image-uploading

I'm in the process of building a site that will help to organize my business. But I'm at a roadblock. Our site is coded in PHP and MySQL and as it currently stands, our contractors can upload images to our site, our site relabels the pictures and associates them with a work order (for ability to search later, if needed), then stores the images in our database.

However, what I want to do is have the images uploaded to their respective work order on our supplier's site. I have contacted our supplier and they will not allow us to access their server directly through the POST commands. So I'm curious if there is a way to still have our images uploaded from our site to our supplier's site. Their site is password protected. On their site, I find the work order associated to the work order and manually upload the images, but I'd like to find a way to do this automatically. The work order numbers between their site and ours are the same. Any ideas?

**New Info**

The comment I left below just states that I have to actually manually click the upload button, choose which photos to upload, then click "upload" to have the images uploaded. FTP is not allowed either.

Comment: "On their site, I find the work order associated to the work order and manually upload the images" however you do this manually you will be able to do it with a script. At a guess your using ftp, php has a full set of ftp functions

Comment: @dagon - What I mean by manually is not FTP but they have a button that says "Upload images". I click that and a browser opens that lets me browse to the pictures and select which ones I want to upload, then I finish by clicking "upload". Sorry for the ambiguity. They won't allow ftp connection either.

Comment: I don't know much about PHP since I'm just starting, but I know some types of libraries are available on most languages, including PHP. You should look into cUrl or some web scraping libraries to simulate sessions / interaction as you would in a browser. Someone more knowledgeable about PHP can probably recommend some good libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "manually" you mean all by www after logging in,  you can use CURL to simulate login session to their website (access login page to obtain session cookie, then post login data with that session cookie, and then with authorized session cookie you can GET/POST whatever you want from their website as authorized user). Use Firebug to track what requests are made and what data are passed from/to their website.

Since using CURL can be painfull (it's syntax is far from user friendly) you can try grab and extract Zend_Http from Zend Framework so you will have very easy syntax and it even work without CURL if you haven't it on your servers.

Answer (score 0):

if they will grant you ftp access you can programatically transfer the images to them that way
or if they have some sort of api exposing methods to upload images

Comment: They won't grant FTP access. Any other ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Remote posting to their site via curl

Answer (score 0):

By "manually upload", you mean via FTP? You can do it with PHP. [Here is the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-put.php).

For security reasons, I suggest you create an FTP user on your client's server which only has access to the images directory, and connect trough that account.

Comment: Please see the edit above about not being able to use FTP. Any other ideas? Thanks.